# A word to refer who doesn't want to study anything

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I need to know if there is a word to refer to someone who doesn't want study anything, who is a bad student etc.

Example:

> He was a bad student because he didn't study anything.

I would like know if I can replace "didn't study anything" with an adjective.

Comment: It's common to wait longer before accepting an answer on ELL. One of the benefits is that you are likely to receive more answers that way. Take a look at [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: I unmarked the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common word *lazy* can apply here.

> [lazy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lazy)
>
> 1. :  not liking or willing to act or work
>
> *He was a bad student because he was **lazy***.

In this context, *lazy* implies that he did not do his work or study.

Specifically, to suggest that a student did not *want* to study, you could say

> 1. [disinterested](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disinterested)
>      :  not having the mind or feelings engaged :  not interested
>      He was a bad student because he was *disinterested* (in school, studies, etc).
> 2. [apathetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic)
>      :  having little or no interest or concern :  indifferent
>      He was a bad student because he was *apathetic* (towards school, studies, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Although **lazy** is often used, in academia there are a wider variety of words that can be used with less negative connotations.

We can say that a student is **unengaged**, **unfocussed** or **detached**. We avoid lazy because sometimes the fault is not always with the student but due to other circumstances either inside the class or elsewhere. It could result from sickness or inability to understand the teacher (such as being weak at understanding a second language etc.)

The aim of a good teacher is to get all their students **engaged** and **focussed** and overcome their difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit obscure and underutilized in my opinion, but I always liked to use the word insouciant for students like that.

noun:

"The English Professor had to bear the constant insouciance of the Engineering and Science majors in his Technical Writing class."

adjective:

"The interns have a surprisingly insouciant attitude toward learning; perhaps the cause is that we only pay them minimum wage?"

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is **unmotivated**:

> 1. Not having interest in or enthusiasm for something, especially work or
>      study. ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unmotivated))

If you're unmotivated, you have no **motivation**:

> ...
>
> 2. the state or condition of being motivated or having a strong reason to act or accomplish something: *We know that these students
>      have strong motivation to learn*. . . .
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/motivation))

These terms are heavily associated with students (and young people in general), as suggested by the definitions above. (The [Google Image result for "unmotivated"](https://www.google.com/search?q=unmotivated&pws=0&biw=1680&bih=867&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzhNTE9MjOAhUHwWMKHQasC44Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=_) is also instructive.) I suspect educators like this terminology in part because there's an implication with *unmotivated* students that the right teaching approach or subject matter could change the student's attitude toward learning and studying. Some other words sound more like an inherent predisposition or character flaw, which would be a lot harder to influence for a teacher.

So you could say

> He was a bad student because he **was unmotivated**.

or

> He was a bad student because he **had no motivation**.